# How to check equality of two Solr Fields?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am facing a situation where I need to fetch all those records from Solr server with a condition that `field_1.value != field_2.value`.

Here `field_1` and `field_2` are Solr field names of my schema.

I tried `!(creation_date = last_edited_date)` but it doesn't works. This returns me all Solr documents Solr server contains while executing the query.

Can anyone please share how to get those records from Solr where `!(creation_date = last_edited_date)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK date comparison isn't as straight forward as other fields.

There are two options that comes to mind

- Have another computed field (boolean) `creation_date_equals_last_edited` and set it to true for documents matching it while indexing. Use this field as a filter criteria.
- Use `frange`, `incl` and `sub` to compute this in query time. An example -

  fq={!frange l=0 incl=false}sub(creation_date,last_edited_date)

If you want tolerance in the date diff (due to marginal timestamp difference), you could possibly use the `scale` function query.

Reference: [Solr Function QUery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)